# Precise Method of Failure Detection with Intel's Adapter Fault Tolerance NIC Teaming in Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows, networking, nic, intel, network-teaming

What are the details of the method(s) that Intel Adapter Fault Tolerance (AFT) uses for the detection of failed links in Windows Server 2008 R2?

Answer (score 3):

Hopefully this answers your question:

http://www.intel.com/network/connectivity/resources/doc_library/white_papers/254031.pdf

> Inherent in all teaming technologies is network-connection fault
>   tolerance or AFT. In order for AFT to work, at least two network
>   connections must be present and have links in the same network.
>   These two network connections indicate to the system whether 
>   or not they have network connectivity using several different
>   mechanisms. Briefly, these mechanisms are as follows:
>
> - Probe Packets — the teamed adapters send and receive probe
>     packets to determine the presence or state of each adapter in 
>     the team.
> - Activity-Based Tolerance — when probe packets are not used, 
>     or do not reach their destination, selection of a Primary (or active)
>     Adapter is made by sensing activity on the link.
> - Link-Based Tolerance — when neither probe packets nor activitybased tolerance are available or successful, link-based tolerance 
>     is used to check the links of the teamed adapters to select a
>     Primary Adapter.

(further detail starts on page 6)